# SQL Query for SSRS Report Visual Studio Query Designer

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, query-designer

Can someone please help with an SQL Query I am facing.

Currently I am using Visual Studio 2013 Query Designer for my SSRS reports and I'm trying to select Students that are enrolled at their current School. However when testing my query for a selected student, it is returning all possible schools and saying the student has attended all 317 of them which is incorrect. My question is how do I find the school that a student has attended/attending?

The query code is below:

```
SELECT Person.Firstname, Person.Surname, Company.Name AS School, Company.CompanyCategory, Student.StudentNumber
FROM   Student INNER JOIN
       Person ON Student.ID = Person.ID CROSS JOIN
       Company
WHERE  (Company.CompanyCategory = 'Delivery Location') AND (Student.StudentNumber = '....')
```

Comment: why u are doing cross join with Company  ...

Comment: Have tried left, right and full joins and get "Error in join expression. Unable to parse query text." I also read "If, WHERE clause is used with CROSS JOIN, it functions like an INNER JOIN." @sandeeprawat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sandeep mentioned, you are cross joining to `Company` (I'm assuming this is school?). You'll probably have to `INNER JOIN` to Company and specify a `JOIN` clause. The table `Student` might have `CompanyID` or something? You can `JOIN` that on the `Company.ID`.
So the query becomes something like this:

```
SELECT Person.Firstname, Person.Surname, Company.Name AS School, Company.CompanyCategory, Student.StudentNumber
FROM   Student INNER JOIN
       Person ON Student.ID = Person.ID INNER JOIN
       --Not sure if CompanyID is the right field
       Company ON Student.CompanyID = Company.ID
WHERE  (Company.CompanyCategory = 'Delivery Location') AND (Student.StudentNumber = '....')
```